# When is a variable with a postfix operator actually incremented?

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following code:

```
int x = 5;
System.out.println(x++);              // Will print 5
System.out.println("Random code");    // Will write "Random code" 
System.out.print(x):                  // Will write 6
```

My question is: On what line is x actually incremented? Immediately after the postfix? Or right before when the variable is called next in order?

I have heard about sequence points having something to do with the postfix and prefix operators.  This is mainly why I asked.

Comment: Well the postfix form first returns the current value of the expression and THEN performs the increment operation on that value. So it'll be incremented on line 5 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `x` will be incremented right after it is printed (in this case). What happens is the comparison/ print/ some other operation is performed on the variable, and then directly after such operation, it gets incremented. The same thing will happen if you have something like
`int z = 0;
if (1 > z++) {
    system.out.println (z)
}`
, it will print 1.

EDIT: There are no sequence points in java. Read this for more information:
[sequence point concept in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720458/sequence-point-concept-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The postfix form first returns the current value of the expression and THEN performs the increment operation on that value. So it'll be incremented on line 5 itself.

An example of this is the classic for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
  //something
}
```

We often [hear that i++ could be replaced by ++i](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467944/792238) , because the third conditional statement of the for-loop is evaluated there itself.

So if `i = 5`, it'd be incremented to 6 on that statement itself and then proceed to the for-loop's body. If postfix behaved such that `i` only got incremented next time it's accessed, then `i` would've remained 5 thruout that iteration of the loop which would've been entirely different than doing `++1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write that code

```
x++
```

That returns x value  for you and increment x by 1.

So it incremented on line no 5 itself.