# What is the result of i == (i = 2)?

Tags: java, c, language-lawyer, variable-assignment, side-effects

Run the following code:

```
// In Java, output #####
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;

    if(i == (i = 2)) {
        System.out.println("@@@@@");
    } else {
        System.out.println("#####");
    }
}
```

But:

```
// In C, output @@@@@，I did test on Clion(GCC 7.3) and Visual Studio 2017
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 1;

    if(i == (i = 2)) {
        printf("@@@@@");
    } else {
        printf("#####");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The motivation for asking this question comes from the following code:

```
// The code is from the JDK 11 - java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
// I am curious about the behavior of the variable prev.
public final int getAndUpdate(IntUnaryOperator updateFunction) {
    int prev = get(), next = 0;
    for (boolean haveNext = false;;) {
        if (!haveNext)
            next = updateFunction.applyAsInt(prev);
        if (weakCompareAndSetVolatile(prev, next))
            return prev;
        haveNext = (prev == (prev = get()));
    }
}
```

So, how to explain the above two different execution modes?

Comment: One explains the two different execution modes by first noting that those are two entirely different languages. They happen to share *some* syntax, but that's where the similarities end.

Comment: The result is : a messy code. Better not imitate this unless you are running for a java obfuscation contest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logic differences in C and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028464/logic-differences-in-c-and-java)

Comment: (although the specific operator used (==, ++, =, etc.) are different, the answer (it's well defined in Java, sequence point --> undefined behavior) is the same)

Comment: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/995714)

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, that would have answered your question for you, especially if you'd tried clang.  `warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]`.  https://godbolt.org/z/UtGRVO

Comment: @theg Why should their "motivation" matters? The answers in both posts are idential, no?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck After your edit, the question is still valid and is no longer a duplicate, but **the top voted answer contains a lot of unrelated parts** (and the "two execution mode" statement no longer makes sense).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Please don't edit the question in a way that changes what the OP is asking, particularly if there are highly-voted answers addressing the original question. If you feel the question is not a valid/good one, closevote/downvote and move on.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck See the revision history.

Comment: Btw, is there a reason for not accepting an answer? :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Just found the "accept" feature...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The *behaviour* of a C program that executes the expression `i == (i = 2)` is *undefined*.

It comes from [C11 6.5p22](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2):

> 2. If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.84)

The `i` on the left-hand side of `==` is a value computation on the value of scalar object `i` and the right-hand side `i = 2` has a side effect of assigning the value `2` to `i`. The LHS and RHS of `==` are unsequenced w.r.t. each other. Hence the entire program is meaningless in C.

Compile with `gcc -Wall` and GCC will spit out:

```
unsequenced.c:5:16: warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     if(i == (i = 2)) {
             ~~~^~~~
```

---

Unlike C, Java guarantees the *evaluation order* for operands (left-to-right), therefore

```
haveNext = (prev == (prev = get()));
```

is correct in Java. The value of LHS is determined strictly before the evaluation of the side effect on the RHS occurs.

In C you **have** to write this as something like

```
newPrev = get();
haveNext = (prev == newPrev);
prev = newPrev;
```

Comment: Why is `i` on the LHS a value computation? Is it specified somewhere in the Standard?

Comment: @SomeName of course it is specified somewhere in the standard. :D

Comment: So how about reference? :) The only I could find was the `value` term defined in 3.19, but no `value computation` defined there.

Comment: @SomeName you need to infer it from way too many places in the prose :/ the [footnote 84](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note84) however can be used as a shortcut. If `i` there was not a value of an expression then            `a[i++] = i;` would be defined. Footnotes are not normative though.

Comment: @SomeName [5.1.2.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p2) says "value computation of lvalue expression", which is a case here, `i` is an lvalue and its value need to be computed, as it is not an operand. [6.3.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2) says "converted to the value stored in the designated object", but this is the one referred to by 5.1.2.3p2

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.

Comment: *it is an operand

Comment: Interestingly, clang decides to evaluate in the opposite order from gcc, and constant-propagation gives us `####` instead of `@@@@`.  https://godbolt.org/z/UtGRVO (And its warning is more descriptive: `warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]`, and enabled even without `-Wall`.)

Comment: Intuitively, it feels like the RHS can only be computed by returning `i` after assigning into it (i.e. `int& operator=(...)`), so there should be an implicit sequence point or something. Instead, one should think of the RHS as `i` and the comparison `==` ordering undefined w.r.t. the assignment `=`?

Comment: @imallett but this is C not C++

Comment: @AnttiHaapala And `i`, being an `int`, wouldn't have a user-defined operator anyway. The point is the grammar: the construction `foo=bar` returns `foo&` (even if references are not exposed in C).

Comment: @imallett incorrect, in C the assignment has a value of an expression, it is definitely *not* an lvalue.

Answer (score 16):

The [Java Language Specification (§15.7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) states:

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear
>   to be evaluated in a specific *evaluation order*, namely, from left to right.

The [specification (§15.21.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) also states that:

> The value produced by the `==` operator is `true` if the value of the left-hand
>   operand is equal to the value of the right-hand operand; otherwise, the result is
>   `false`.

Therefore in Java, the if-statement at runtime would look like the following, which obviously evaluates to `false`:

```
if (1 == 2) {

}
```

In C, it is simply undefined (see [Antti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577775/7294647)).

Answer (score 5):

In C, the behavior of `i == (i = 2)` is undefined because it attempts to both update an object and use that object’s value in a computation without an intervening sequence point.  The result will vary based on the compiler, compiler settings, even the surrounding code.